# project directory for common lisp projects in Windows 10

Tags: windows, common-lisp, slime, quicklisp

I am trying to follow a [tutorial](http://xach.livejournal.com/278047.html?thread=668191) on creating a main folder that slime will automatically check for when I run (quickload:"project"). It says to create a config at `~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d/projects.conf` and I am unsure if that holds for Windows.

I am using Clozure 1.11 on Windows 10.

Any helpful suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: If this check is being run from Emacs, then it probably applies. Emacs will interpret `~` as being either in `%USERPROFILE%` or `%APPDATA%` or one of those related directories; I don't remember which. Just try creating the file (from within Emacs so `~` is automatically resolved) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

"~/" is Unixy shorthand for "your home directory," which is something that different Windows programs can disagree how to interpret.

To see what directory your Lisp believes to be your home directory, evaluate

```
(user-homedir-pathname)
```

from within your Common Lisp REPL.

I think that, on Windows, some builds of Emacs may differ about their idea as to what your home directory is — ie, it's quite possible for Clozure to think `/Users/hramirez/` is your home, but Emacs to decide upon `/Users/hramirez/Application Settings/` or even `/Program Files/GNU/Emacs/24.1/` or something.

Note that, you say “Slime” would check, but in fact I think you're looking to configure where *Quicklisp* will look for local projects.

Comment: okay, I can run that in the repl, but how do I find out where it's looking for the config file?

Comment: Replace "~" with the home dir pathname.